# How to run Wilcoxon signed-rank test for pairwise comparison of two factors with three variables each?

Tags: nonparametric, wilcoxon-signed-rank, friedman-test

I performed a study where I took 9 measurements from each participant for 2 factors (time/ location) and 3 variables each. These created the following combinations:
T1L1, T1L2, T1L3, T2L1, T2L2, T2L3, T3L1, T3L2, T3L3.

My data is not normally distributed. I ran the Friedman test and Wilcoxon signed-rank test for above combinations. All of the combinations are statistically significant.

Now, I am interested in performing the following pairwise comparisons: T1-T2, T2-T3, T1-T3, L1-L2, L1-L3, L2-L3. Any suggestions? One idea I can think of is just taking means and performing Wilcoxon signed-rank test. For example for T1-T2, I take Mean(T1L1, T1L2, T1L3) and Mean (T2L1, T2L2, T2L3) and then perform Wilcoxon signed-rank test. Is it okay to do this? Are there any other better alternatives?

Wilcoxon signed-rank test

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are looking for a non-parametric alternative to multivariate ANOVA. Although I have never used this, this R package might do exactly what you are looking for [npmv](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v076i04).